# what is reason for i couldn't update real sysdate in oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, sql-update, prepared-statement, sysdate

When I execute the code i got wrong sysdate for my oracle database.But when I execute that code on my terminal it updated real sysdate.

```
con = apprEvent.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EVENTS SET E_STATUS='Approved',
                                               E_AUTH_TIME=SYSDATE WHERE E_ID=" + eid);
queryRes = pst1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What is the "wrong sysdate"?  And what is the "right sysdate" in this case?

Comment: actually when I execute that query it update wrong value for sysdate. As a example when actual time is 10.00.00am it update as 3.00.00pm like wise. But when I execute in terminal without prepared statement tag and commit it update real sysdate of 10.00.00am.

Comment: have you checked that your clock and the clock on the db os is the same ?

Comment: Yes.When it is run on terminal without preparesatement tag and only update query, it update actual sysdate.

Comment: UPDATE EVENTS SET E_STATUS='Approved', E_AUTH_TIME=SYSDATE WHERE E_ID=231; In terminal above code update right sysdate.

Comment: what is reason for update wrong sysdate?

Comment: are you SURE your terminal and your db are operating in the same timezone and are set to the same time?

Comment: Thnx I got it.That's not in same timezone.Thanx again.